# Show places more then 50 kms in google place API

Tags: ios

How to find places with distance more then 50 kms? i am using google place api for that but it is providing only 50 kms places. please help

Comment: Please give some efforts on google before asking here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iOS Human Interface Guidelines it is documented: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Here as a Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you edit the actual icon sizes into your answer here? Wouldn't be unusual for Apple to change the URLs to their docs and make your answer unfortunately useless. Thanks!